# How service provider get enough ip addresses

Tags: ip-address

there is something in my head that drives me crazy .

let's suppose that a internet service provider has the following IP address range:

`41.96.0.0  to 41.111.255.255` that give him `1048576` IP Address for clients.

Now the crazy thing that i want to understand, i know that every machine has a unique ip address and it's impossible to find two machines with one ip address (please correct me if i am wrong ) ; but this internet service provider has about 3,000,000 clients and every client has a unique ip ! how do they do it ? how do they provide all of these clients unique ip addresses ?

it's logical that num clients = number of addresses

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Until recently, service providers would simply justify their IP address needs to one of the 5 worldwide regional IP address registries by documenting how many customers they had and how many IP addresses each customer required (generally just 1 each for residential, but potentially more) and the registry would allocate to them as many as were needed. In IPv4, this is not true any longer, because the supply of IPv4 addresses is exhausted. ISPs and the 5 regional IP address registries are currently scraping the bottom of the IPv4 barrel.

When there are no more IPv4 addresses left to assign, ISPs will be forced to use NAT (Network Address Translation) to place more than one customer on each IP address. Mobile ISPs by and large have already been putting their customers behind NAT for years. End users have been doing it for even longer in order to be able to connect more than one device behind consumer-grade Internet connections that come with only one IPv4 address.

In IPv6 the number of available IP addresses is not expected to be a problem for the entire lifetime of the protocol.

Comment: i understand how NAT works in LAN (few machines connect together in LAN then a server manage the unique IP i the lan) , but i don't understand how it's work without LAN at all . does the ISP has any kind of networks that connect few machines together then give him a unique IP Adderss.because i know that i am not connected to any WAN or LAN .

Comment: NAT is not "managed" by a server, but rather by a router. Now consider: the definition of an internet is a set of networks (WANs or LANs) interconnected with routers so that they can all reach each other. So yes, of course, ISPs have networks. And to your final point, you are surely connected to some kind of WAN or LAN or network of some kind, otherwise your computer is standalone and not connected to the Internet!